# Problema con despliegue de una pirámide invertida

Tags: c#

Bien, realize un algoritmo que construye una pirámide invertida solo por diversion. Aparentemente todo estaba bien, y en la corrida de escritorio que hice a mano del Código(realice todo a mano) también estaba bien, pero la problemática es que no me despliega como debería, es decir tengo un problema con los espacios en blanco.

El programa pregunta;

Ingrese la altura: 4(por ejemplo)

luego debería de devolver un grafico como este:

```
               * * * *
                * * *
                 * *
                  *
```

En vez de eso, tengo este resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podrán apreciar, el problema son los espacios, creí estar bien por que según yo, en el papel me funcionaba, pero ahora que lo ejecuto no se imprime del todo correcto. Dejo el Código junto a una descripción de como fue mi abstracción conjuntamente con lo que he intentado hacer para solucionar dicho problema.

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
```

// Declaracion de variables; altura, limite, cotadorpar, contadorinpar, contadorblancos.
int alt = 0;
int li = 0;
int contp = 0;
int conti = 0;
int contb = 0;
int j = 0;

//Ingreso altura o limite

```
        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la altura del triangulo");
        alt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

//Establezco el limite de cuantos * se van a imprimir despues de cada salto de linea

```
        li = alt - 1;
```

//Este for controla el numero de filas de la piramide, osea la altura.

```
        for(int i=0; i<=(alt-1); i++)
        {
```

//declaro que estos contadores vuelvan a cero despues de un salto de linea cuando los asteriscos y espacios en blanco se hayan impreso.

```
            conti = 0;
            contp = 0;
            contb = 0;
```

//Este for controla cuantos * y espacios en blanco se van a imprimir en cada fila

```
            for(j=0; j<=((alt*2)-1); j++)
            {
```

//condicion, de segunda fila en adelante

```
                if(i>=1)

                {
```

// Como estamos en la fila nro 1, entonces el asterisco no sera impreso desde j=0, sino desde j=1, por lo que no mando a imprimir un espacio en blanco, si mas bien, le digo que J tenga el mismo valor de I(ubicar primera posicion para imprimir el asterisco)

```
                    j = i + contb + conti + contp;
```

//Condición que hace la magia. Si J e I son impares y el limite correspondiente a aquella fila son correctos imprima *

```
                    if((j%2!=0)&&(i%2!=0)&& conti <=li)
                    {

                        Console.Write("*");
```

//contador de numero de * en la fila

```
                        conti++;
                    }
```

//Caso contrario imprima vacio

```
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
```

//contador de vacios
contb++;
}
//Condicion que hace la magia. Si J e I son pares y el limite correspondiente a aquella fila son correctos imprima(es decir ubicar posicion, imprimir y contar desde alli.

```
                    if ((j % 2 == 0) && (i % 2 == 0) && contp <= li)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                        contp++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        contb++;
                    }
                }
```

//Caso contrario, no ubicar el primer asterisco, solo imprimir y contar desde posicion cero.

```
                else
                {
                    if (j % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                }
            }
```

//Salto de linea para dar paso a la siguiente fila

```
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
```

//Cuando el limite llega a cero, el programa termina

```
            li--;
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

codigo unitario:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int alt = 0;
        int li = 0;
        int contp = 0;
        int conti = 0;
        int contb = 0;
        int j = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la altura del triangulo");
        alt = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        li = alt - 1;

        for(int i=0; i<=(alt-1); i++)
        {
            conti = 0;
            contp = 0;
            contb = 0;
            j = 0;

            for(j=0; j<=((alt*2)-1); j++)
            {

                if(i>=1)
                {
                    j = i + contb + conti + contp;

                    if((j%2!=0)&&(i%2!=0)&& conti <=li)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                        conti++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        contb++;
                    }

                    if ((j % 2 == 0) && (i % 2 == 0) && contp <= li)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                        contp++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                        contb++;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (j % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        Console.Write("*");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            li--;
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Trato de ser lo mas objetivo posible, y explicar como pense este problema, que para mi tiene loguica pero el debug me dice que no, cual es mi error?

Comment: No entiendo la lógica tan complicada que tienes. Basta con 1) imprimir tantos espacios en blanco al inicio como [número de línea - 1]  y 2) imprimir * y " " alternados, tantos "*" como [altura - el número de línea + 1].

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo el ejemplo resolviendo tu problema un poco mas corto.

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int Altura = 0; //Cantidad de niveles hacia abajo.
        int Ancho = 0; //El mismo ancho tomara
        int EspacioEnBlanco = 0; //Quitaremos el ancho en cada vuelta y se lo sumaremos para darle la cantidad necesaria a separarse del borde.

        Console.WriteLine("Ingrese la altura");

        Altura = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Ancho = Altura;

        for (int i = 0; i < Altura; i++)  //Comenzas diciendo el alto a dibujar.
        {
            for (int A = 0; A < Ancho; A++) //Dibujas * por cada linea
            {
                if (EspacioEnBlanco > 0) //Si es espacio en blanco es 0 lo salteamos para que no dibuje en la primera linea.
                {
                 //Al entrar aqui sera la resta entre Alto - ancho -> ya que al ancho lo decrementamos con cada vuelta y esto hace la suma que debe tener el blanco.
                    for (int x = 0; x < EspacioEnBlanco; x++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }
                    EspacioEnBlanco = 0;
                    // Para que entre una sola vez por fila volvemos a colocar en 0 a Espacio en blanco.
                }
                Console.Write("*");
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            Ancho--;
            EspacioEnBlanco = Altura - Ancho;
            Console.WriteLine("");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.....");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta muy genial, pero lo único que quiesce saber es en donde fallo yo, y como podrida arreglarlo, debido a que según yo, todo estaba bien, no debía de fallar, y bueno, talvez es por que alguna de mis sintaxis en el for no estén del todo correcta.

Comment: Quiero saber donde falla, y el por que de la falla, no otro programa, quiese saber eso primero, y luego trabajare en optimización

Comment: Inicialmente falla donde el codigo es muy complicado de entender, mientras mas simple mejor. Te estaria faltando sumar los espacios en blanco mientras restas los caracteres que imprimis